Do we need to update the "politics" tag to match the questions it has been added to?
The description of tag politics mentions only personal political opinions and such. However, it seems to be used almost entirely for such things as political factions within departments and universities. That is, groups with competing, even warring, opinions about academia itself or the fields of the individuals. Tag interpersonal-issues overlaps with this idea, but isn't quite the same.
The current guidance is more of a footnote to the concept than actual guidance.
I was tempted to remove the tag from a recent post until I checked the historical usage.
Should the description of politics be updated to match the usage?

First, I would rename this tag to either university-politics or academic-politics. The latter is a bit broader and recognizes that not all academics/researchers are in universities.
My suggestion would be something like the following:
This tag is to be used for questions about intra-university factions and disputes and how they might be resolved. It is not about national, governmental, or regional political parties or factions or opinions.
The longer form might include:
The [university-politics] tag is for questions that might be normally described as "department politics" though disputes and factions between rather than strictly within departments are also covered.
This tag is also appropriate for such disputes within research labs that may not be associated with a university, but have much the same purpose as university research.
For questions related to the academic field of political science, use the [political-science] tag.
For traditional political questions the companion site https://politics.stackexchange.com/ is more appropriate.

Update: this is done. The old politics tag has been renamed university-politics, and the guidance updated. A few questions will need to be retagged.

I agree with this. I just had a look at some of the questions, and the tag and its use are quite messy. Often, it is also used alongside or instead of political-science which is explicitly mentioned in the politics description as something that should not be done.
My suggestion would be to

in any case remove/replace it in all instances where political-science is the correct tag

and to

either rename the tag into political-opinion to make clear(er) what it is about without having to look at the description (which I guess many people don't do). In this case, all instances where the question is actually about department politics, the tag should be removed
or change the tag description to fit the scope of political factions at unis. In this case, all instances where the question is actually about political opinions, the tag should be removed. Some of them might be fit for retagging with interpersonal-issues.
implement a combination of both: have both politics (or even department-politics or similar) and political-opinion, each with the above proposed meaning.


However it works out "departmental-politics" would be a good synonym.

Update: this is also done. In addition to the university-politics tag, there is now a political-opinion tag. Some of the questions currently tagged university-politics probably need the tags changed to political-opinion.

I would separate into two different tags:

a new political-issues tag for questions like this one where OP is concerned about publishing in an Israeli journal, and this one where OP is concerned that their degree will be worth less if they graduate from countries involved in international conflicts. We can describe it as "when global or regional politics affect academic careers."
a departmental-politics tag for questions where the OP is concerned about inter- or intra-departmental politics. This could be a rename of the existing tag, and then we clean up. We should clarify that this is not just for interpersonal conflicts with one or two individuals, but a situation where different factions of the department have different goals and it is necessary to navigate this environment.

Neither of these should usually overlap with political-science (unless OP is a political scientist and this is relevant to the question). I found only one clear case where politics and political science were incorrectly applied to the same question, and I already retagged that one.

I like this idea, but political-issues might need a better, more specific name. "politics"and its variants still causes US people to think Democrat v Republican rather than the wider definition, and similar elsewhere, I'd guess. Thinking-Cap time.

Agree, I've spent days trying to think of a better one. I like "global-politics" or "national-politics", since that is unambiguous and covers most questions, but that excludes regional issues (e.g., if a prof in Ann Arbor was running for mayor and had questions, that sounds interesting, but global-politics seems a little grandiose). And regional-politics seems like it rules out global issues, such as the cold war.

"professional-risk" seems to have the right concept but isn't obvious.

@cag51 I guess "extrainstitutional-politics" would imply an appropriate scope, but it is rather awkward.

And "university-politics" or even "academic-politics" might be better than "department-politics".

"personal-standards" for such posts as the reluctance to publish with an Israeli journal? I'd hesitate with "personal-opinions" though.

All the answers basically agree, so I'm inclined to go for it and use the verbiage in the higher-voted answers (political-opinion and departmental-politics). I like some of the other name suggestions here, but I suppose we should follow the votes.

@cag51 but as you posted the answer later, I am unsure if the people really agree more with our suggestions. I am unsure if a second Meta post with a poll just for the renaming would help. I am unsure if both suggested tags would be a fit for all situations, e.g. https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/78159/are-professors-allowed-to-participate-in-political-activities seems to not be about an opinion, but rather about mixing politics and academia.

@Sursula: another interpretation is that with only 3 upvotes and answers that basically agree, people are in favor of any reasonable solution and don't care too much about the details. So if you, me, and @Buffy agree on something, we can probably push it through. I'm good with political-opinion and departmental politics (which came from your answer). I think we can write the tag guidance for political-opinion in such a way to make clear that it includes the question you linked (professors engaging in campaign work is an offshoot of their political opinions). Thoughts?

Again, university-politics is better than departmental. Academic-politics may be better yet. See my revised answer. It would be nice to make the change without driving too many questions to the top of the active list at once. That may be a mod superpower, but not mine. That is why I didn't try to change things on my own.

My concern about university-politics is that it excludes questions with other types of politics, such as when dealing with journals, industry R&D, or government sponsors. academic-politics is good, but we have a long-standing convention of not beginning tags with academic-, since everything on this site is inherently academic.

Hmmm, is dealing with journals or having opinions about them a form of "politics"? I think I wouldn't support this tag for such things. Conventions can have exceptions. I don't think many other tags would find that qualifier useful.

Of course not every question about dealing with journals would be appropriate for the "departmental-politics" tag. But for example if your grad student pissed off a reviewer, and now there is a angry back-and-forth "in public," trying to diplomatically smooth things over might be considered "departmental-politics." (Dealt with this once.)

Anyway, I am losing patience with this. If we cannot agree on two tag names, maybe we should just leave the status quo.

@cag51 I'll butt in and vote for [tag:university-politics] as it clarifies the difference between external politics and institutional politics, even if it is slightly imprecise for the occasional question.

@AzorAhai-him- I second the suggestion

@AzorAhai-him-, that works well enough for me. But leaving it "as is" is the worst option.

I've made an edit to my suggestion tag wiki.

Sounds like a plan then.
